# Can Romulans initiate a mind meld?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, tv, telepathy, romulan

Given the common ancestry of the Romulans and the Vulcans, and that the Romulans emigrated only about 2,000 years ago (in the TNG era: a drop in the bucket in terms of evolutionary biology), should there be a number of Romulans capable of initiating a mind meld? Is it ever explicitly shown that they can mind meld or that they specifically can't mind meld?

Comment: I don't have the episode on hand to check, but I _think_ ENT 4x14 "The Aenar" mentions or hints that Romulans do have extremely weak telepathic ability.  If it was there, it was an offhand comment and not in the episode summary.

Comment: It's also a major plot point in ENT that Vulcans only *just* started using mind melds again in the 22nd century.

Comment: **Spoiler alert**. 
Recent episode in Star Trek: Picard (S01E07) shows commodore Oh mind melds with Jurati to get her spying on Picard's mission. 

Commodore Oh is the federation's head of security, and is probably imposing as a Vulcan though she's part of the Zhat Vash/Tak Shiar, hence, most likely Romulan.

Comment: Spoiler: Picard S01E08 wasn't Oh revealed to be half Vulcan/half Romulan?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They used to have telepathic abilities, but not anymore. [Expanded universe reference](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Romulan) on Memory Alpha states:

> It is explained in *Vulcan's Soul* that the Romulans rejected the
>   telepathy of the Vulcans and slaughtered or enslaved the telepathic
>   ones among them during their exodus to the Romulan system: the
>   telepaths became the [Remans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Reman).

Comment: Aha.  The Reman article references the ENT episodes I was thinking of in the question's comments.  They must have been mentioned, but it was before I knew the difference between a Reman and a Romulan (I'd watched ENT before any other series)

Answer (score 4):

Also the Romulans missed out on the spiritual/social Renaissance that the Vulcans underwent where they tamed their emotions and mastered their minds.  Where Vulcans began a process of reflection and mental discipline, the Romulans focused on conquest and empire building.  Not only that but, as mentioned by @HNL, they rejected the meditative lifestyle entirely, going out of their way to excise those with telepathic potential from their society.

Answer (score -3):

The Romulans demonstrate some latent telepathic ability in the two-part episode [TNG: Gambit](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Gambit,_Part_II_(episode)) where a Romulan uses the Vulcan psionic resonator that "*focuses and amplifies telepathic energy*" Thus they demonstrably have similar telepathic capabilities to Vulcans.

Comment: Just to be clear: I didn't have the reputation to add the information as a comment, or I would have done so.

Comment: The "Romulan" in question was [actually a Vulcan posing as a Romulan](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/T%27Paal_%28isolationist%29).

Comment: It's a rather strange isolationist that seeks help from outside the group she wishes to isolate.  Also, the talk page seems to indicate that the claim of her being an isolationist may not come from a canon source.

Comment: Grrr . . I meant to say her being a *Vulcan* isolationist may have come from a non-canon source.  I'll have to watch that episode again sometime with this in mind.

Comment: Skimming over the transcripts, it's true, it's not explicitly stated that she's *Vulcan*. On the other hand, I *think* it is made to look like she is indeed Vulcan. What we know is: Toward the mercenaries, she poses as a Romulan. Toward Picard, she poses as a Vulcan V'Shar operative. Also, there is a group of Vulcan isolationists trying to get hold of the artifact. It does not seem like the Romulans have any part in this; toward the mercenaries, a criminal Romulan might just appear as less suspicious than a criminal Vulcan. Instead, it seems reasonable that Tallera belongs to one of the ...

Comment: ... groups that we know are involved with the incident (if only due to Chekhov's gun principle). As she is not with the V'Shar, only the Vulcan isolationists remain, as they wouldn't otherwise have had any other role in the story. (A red herring would be pointless: She's not an isolationist, but actually a ... criminal from an unrelated faction! No, that doesn't work.) Of course, she *might* be a Romulan working with the Vulcan isolationists, but that seems somewhat far-fetched, in particular if we want to use it as evidence for Romulan telepathic abilities.